# GLIBC_2.14' not found - How to update

Tags: linux, glibc

Im trying to use Minergate, but when i want to start it, it gives me that error:

> minergate-cli: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14'
>   not found (required by minergate-cli)

and

> minergate-cli: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15'
>   not found (required by /opt/minergate-cli/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)

I did "sudo apt-get update" and upgrade, but did nothing. I dont know what to do next, anyone got something ? :)

Edit:
I have that linux:

> Linux bukalamaksymilian 2.6.32-042stab108.3 #1 SMP Thu Jun 11 21:06:20 MSK 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Looks like you're missing some compat-type library.  Which Linux distro are you using and what version?  (Likely Ubuntu or Debian, but which one)?

Comment: PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian

Comment: Wheezy is kinda old, and mining programs are notoriously intolerant of old.  See http://somewhatrelated.blogspot.com/2014/10/fixing-glibc-214-not-found-error-in.html?m=1 for a sorta-fix, but you'd be better off using a modern Ubuntu as recommended by the Minergate download page.

Comment: Debian 7 is the previous version, the current one is Debian 8 (Jessie) and has glibc 2.19. You can find upgrade instructions by searching the web, but in principle, the steps are: Change the Debian version in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, do `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`. If you are lucky and there are no conflicts, that's all there is to it.

Comment: @KarstenKoop
Theres an error on dist-upgrade:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Failed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 udev : Breaks: plymouth (< 0.9.0-7) but 0.8.5.1-5 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: mh, plymouth should be 0.9.0-9 in Jessie. As the message says, this could be caused by held packages. Did you exchange all occurences of `wheezy` with `jessie` in /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: Well, all i did is change all "wheezy" to "jassie" in that file, i think this is ... bad ;D ?